# Finding centroid of features within polygon using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, features, centroids

I have some polygon features and within those polygons are some coordinates for some other features.

How do I find the centroid of those coordinate points within the polygon (NOT the geometric centroid of the TAZ)?

Comment: That doesnt make sense can you be more specific? What are the other features within your TAZ polys? polygons or points?

Comment: They are points (coordinates)

Comment: could you edit your quetion with an illustration. Are the coordinates shown as annotations ? Does it come from CAD file ?

Comment: No. The coordinates are stored in a shapefile (point feature dataset). The TAZs are polygon feature dataset. I connected them with the Spatial Join tool. Now I want to know the centroid of the point features within the polygons.

Comment: The `Geometry` class has a `.centroid()` request, which is documented as returning "The true centroid if it is within or on the feature; otherwise, the label point is returned."

Comment: I have tried the "Mean Center" tool to find my desired output. Just asking to verify if this is reasonable?

Comment: No, the Mean Center of a coral reef is in the lagoon. This can be done with Calculate Field if you use `!shape!.centroid().X/Y`

Comment: so if I understand correctly, you want to find the centroid of multiple points. So they would need to be multipoint features then I would think you could use the find centroid tool.
create multipoint feature: 
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/create-point-and-multipoint-features.htm
find centroid:
https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/find-centroids.htm